# How do I read every 2 lines of a text file and save as a string array?

Tags: arrays, sorting, go

I'm trying to read a text file into my program and save the text file as a string array, I have managed to achieve reading all lines into a string array 1 by 1 but I would like to have it so it reads 2 lines into one array. My txt file would look something like this:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

fmt.Println(text[0])
I want it to print:
line1line2

fmt.Println(text[1])
I want it to print:
line3line4

My current code is:

```
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    scanner.Split(bufio.ScanLines)
    var text []string
    for scanner.Scan() {
        text = append(text, scanner.Text())
    }
```

The issue is it's reading each line one by one but I'd want it to read 2 and save it into the array as one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just read the second line within your `for` loop with another call to `scanner.Scan`:

```
var text []string
for scanner.Scan() {
    t := scanner.Text()
    if scanner.Scan() {
        t = t + scanner.Text()
    }
    text = append(text, t)
}
```